# Please, can you help me with this recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int  fun (int x)
 {
      if (x<1)
        return(1);
      else
        printf("%d %d \n", x, fun(x-1));
 }
int main()
 { int x,y;
   x = 5;
   y = fun(x);
   printf("\n x = %d f(x) = %d \n", x, y);
   return 0;
  }
```

This program contains a recursive function that count some numbers. There is something in the output I cannot understand.
There is a screenshot of the output at the following link:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BE4862D617298D2C!886&authkey=!AA03bF8dQ5W4S9Y&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Why the right column (red circuled) is as shown? I thought that this column will be all ones instead of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function `fun` didn't have a return value when x >= 1.

And the 5 is the return value of `printf("%d %d \n", x, fun(x-1));` because it has output 5 characters.

Comment: That is purely coincidental, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 It's undefined but not a coincidence.

Comment: @2501 Oh yes. I just notice that it happened to output 5 characters and the return value of printf is 5...... Maybe there are any relationship between them? In fact I didn't know clearly...

Comment: @hvd It is the very definition of a coincidence.

Comment: @2501 No, it's not. The result of the undefined behaviour is that the compiler generates machine code that causes the return value of `printf` to be passed on to the caller. A coincidence would be an identical return value that happened to be calculated completely independently.

Comment: *The result of the undefined behaviour is that the compiler generates machine code that causes the return value of printf to be passed on to the caller.* is the coincidence I was referring to. You introduced a red herring, and say I was wrong. They could both be coincidences.

Comment: @2501 That's not what the word "coincidence" means: the "co" specifically refers to multiple events, and the only way that makes sense is if those events are the return value of `printf` being 5, and the return value of `fun` being 5. Those being equal is not a coincidence since that's caused by a single related event, and that single related event isn't a coincidence because it's only a single event. You might want to say "random chance" instead of "coincidence" instead.

Comment: @hvd No, it is coincidence. Because it might not work on a different machine. I'm ending this discussion, since it is unproductive.

Comment: @2501 That's fine. I hope it's clear that nobody claimed that it was defined behaviour or that it would work on all machines, though: there's no disagreement there.

Comment: It doesn't work on any machine! Given the fact that it is undefined behaviour, it is a coincidence(!) that it returns a 5. The program is perfectly correct doing anything. Thus returning the value of printf is in fact a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything if `x>=1`, causing undefined behaviour when the execution reaches the end of the function. That means the value could be anything, you got 5 by chance.

> *6.9.1. p12:*
>
> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

The return value is used in your example.

```
int fun(int x)
{
    if (x<1)
        return(1);
    else
        printf("%d %d \n", x, fun(x-1));

    return x ;//just return something
}
```

You probably want to return something relevant to what you function does.